# How to allow the content of 2 DIV side by side of a page to be scroll down or up independently without using frames?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, frames

I have an page written in ASP classic that uses **frameset** containing 2 frames. While the left frame serve to display the menu, the right frame display the page content.

The way the page works, user can independently **scroll down or up** content of either one of the frames.

How can I reproduce the same functionality using only HTML and CSS?

```
<div id="menu-container">
  //menu goes here...
</div>
<div id="main-content">
  //main content here...
</div>
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `overflow: auto` and fixed `height` on parent element.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.left, .right {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

.inner {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi asperiores deleniti culpa voluptatem in esse magnam sequi laborum quas ipsum vel, dolores natus ad reprehenderit enim nihil tenetur eaque, modi.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex repellat architecto ducimus hic. Ratione eius eos, atque, officia nemo quasi beatae voluptatem necessitatibus hic nam aliquid iusto quis laudantium reiciendis!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give each a fixed height like 500px;

Then set the overflow-y property to auto or scroll to enable the scrollbar

`overflow-y: auto;`

here is a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/pablo_tavarez/dobza7gv/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use NiceScroll (`jQuery Plugin`) for your page. You can apply it to a **DIV** object you want.

[image]

[Live demo and sample code.](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/demo.html)

[Download open source code](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll)