# Making two side by side divs scrollable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I really need some help on this please. I literally spent four days to do this but no luck. Then fortunately I was searching for two 100% height side by side divs both scrolling independently if extra contents are added but won't collapse if there is less content than the page height. Here is the solution I found. http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/58mkp/1/

```
    <div class="Container">
    <div class="Header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <p>if The Header height is not fixed, It will span excatly his needed space.</p>
        <p>The Padding/Margin between the header and the content and around the layout is optional</p>
    </div>
    <div class="HeightTaker">
        <div class="Wrapper">
            <div class="LeftNavigation">
                <h1>Left navigation</h1>
                <p>The width of the left navigation is not fixed.</p>
                <p>the left navigation will always span 100% height</p>
            </div>
            <div class="Content">
                <h1>Content</h1>
                <p>The Content div should always span the available Container space.</p>
                <p>If the content exceed the Content available space, it will scroll.</p>
                <p><a target="_blank" href="http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/58mkp/">Here's a demo of this scenario</a></p>
                <p class="Important">This Layout has been tested on: IE10, IE9, IE8, FireFox, Chrome, Safari, Opera. using Pure CSS 2.1 only</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

*
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

html, body, .Container, .LeftNavigation, .Content
{
height: 100%;
}

.Container:before
{
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.HeightTaker
{
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}

.HeightTaker:after
{
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

.Wrapper
{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.LeftNavigation
{
float: left;
}
.LeftNavigation, .Content
{
overflow: auto;
}


/*For demonstration only*/
.Header
{
background-color: #bf5b5b;
text-align: center;
}

.LeftNavigation
{
background-color: #6ea364;
}
.Content
{
background-color: #66cab7;
text-align: center;
}
p
{    
font-size: 1.3em;
}
.Important
{
font-weight: bolder;
color: white;
}
```

But this is in CSS. Can the same thing be achieved in Bootstrap please? And why is the left navigation width not changing? It has not been set as I see? And if possible, can this be achieved in some easier code? I am not much good to understand what's going on actually.

Comment: Note the `overflow: auto;`... might be the thing you want

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974458/how-to-allow-the-content-of-2-div-side-by-side-of-a-page-to-be-scroll-down-or-up/35974533#35974533

Comment: Not in fixed height. I want both of them take 100% height of the browser and scroll if too much content please.